# Lottery numbers and chaos/quantum theory

Tags: statistics, chaos-theory

Please settle an argument if you would be so kind. In a group chat, one person took the position

> 1,2,3,4,5,6 has as much chance of coming out in the lottery as any other six numbers you define, e.g. 3,11,23,33,34,46.

A second person took the position that this was untrue because:

> Those numbers include the randomness of chaos theory, but a perfect sequential number doesn't have that so its chances become slimmer. If you drill down to the mathematics of it at least.

Person two also went to go on to discuss quantum theory as well.

So from a pure statistics point of view, I believe, the first person is correct. My question for you good folks is in two parts (mostly the second part):

1. Is the first quote correct?
2. Even if the first person is correct, are there any theory/basis for the second quote when it comes to the real-world execution of a lottery? Ideally something I can look up and read more about. It's entirely possible they're remembering something valid, but are not quoting it properly.

Comment: I have no idea what the second person is talking about.

Comment: The second statement is not right. It is not worth to continue thinking about it. Every sequence is equiprobable.

Comment: @anomaly That's okay, neither does he.

Comment: Let´s say you have a lottery with $n$ numbers and $m$ numbers are drawn. The probability to draw any specific sequence is always

$$\frac{1}{\binom{N}{m}}$$

Comment: Related thought: I think the *impression* that $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ is less "random" (which might lead to some people agreeing with the second person) is at least in part born of some notion of interchangeability.  The set $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ seems much less fungible than $3, 11, 23, 24, 34, 46$, and along those lines, the probability of getting something "like" $3, 11, 23, 24, 34, 46$ is higher than something like $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$.  (For instance, the actual original set $3, 11, 23, 33, 34, 46$ is "like" $3, 11, 23, 24, 34, 46$, in partial illustration of that fact.)

Comment: "Chaos theory" has nothing to do with "randomness"!  Chao theory deals with *determinate* processes that are so complicated there is no good "closed form" formula.

Comment: Is it possible the second person is talking about [Kolmogorov complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) or something akin to it and confusing the name with chaos theory?

Comment: @user247327 *"Chaos theory" has nothing to do with "randomness"!* – That’s not entirely correct. Sufficiently complex chaotic systems cannot be distinguished from random ones anymore. For example, you could consider any pseudo-random number generator as a (state-discretised approximation of a) chaotic system.

Answer (score 4):

I can *kind of* understand the confusion.  You're more likely to get some "random" set of numbers than you are to get 1,2,3,4,5,6.

But in your example, the set of numbers 3,11,23,33,34,46 is no less random than 1,2,3,4,5,6.  In each instance, you're looking for a specific set of numbers.  The probability of either set is equal.

Basically, person 2 was trying to assign some probabilistic importance to the specific set of numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6; but as far as probability is concerned, the set of 1,2,3,4,5,6 is just as significant as 3,11,23,33,34,46.

The whole bit about [chaos theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory) is nonsense.  Chaos theory relates to the end result being very sensitive to starting conditions for a deterministic system.  The physical number draw in a lottery would involve aspects of chaos theory, in the sense that the system fairly "chaotic" and sensitive to initial conditions. That has no bearing on the difference between either set of numbers, so his statement was very unclear. Randomness is what ensures that 1,2,3,4,5,6 is just as likely as 3,11,23,33,34,46; so what they are saying really made no sense, and actually supports 1,2,3,4,5,6 being as likely as 3,11,23,33,34,46.

Comment: The systems that I have seen that can be modeled by chaos theory involve systems that bifurcate periodically. I am not sure how a lottery might relate to that. A lottery seems too discrete to follow a similar bifurcation scheme as any of the chaotic systems I have looked at. In what way would chaos theory be at all valuable? (I have only a cursory understanding of chaos theory, so I am asking in earnest).

Comment: @InterstellarProbe In the sense that a physical lottery system with balls could be dramatically changed based on initial conditions.  I'm not sure if "valuable" would be the right word; and I removed "good" from my wording to focus more on what I was getting at.  I don't think the concept of chaos theory is particularly valuable here compared to other aspects of the draw.

Comment: @JMac I see, thanks for clarifying. That makes sense. In light of Mitchell Feigenbaum's recent passing, posts about chaos theory have been catching my attention.

Answer (score 1):

> "1,2,3,4,5,6 has as much chance of coming out in the lottery as any
>   other six numbers you define, e.g. 3,11,23,33,34,46"

This is correct.

> "those numbers include the randomness of chaos theory, but a perfect
>   sequential number doesn't have that so its chances become slimmer. if
>   you drill down to the mathematics of it at least".

There is absolutely no truth in this. This is simply nonsense and shouldn't be given a second of thought. *To me* it seems like the person just wanted to sound smart, even though he has no idea what he's talking about.